# ZK Upload Image and Show It

Tags: image, button, upload, zk

how to upload an image and show it on browser using button in zk. I have tried it but the uploaded image did not appear on the browser. please show me what's wrong with my code:

this is the zul file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?init class="org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.AnnotateDataBinderInit" ?>
<window id="win" use="simple.zkoss.project.WindowController">
    <hbox>
        <button id="uploadButton" label="Upload" upload="true" onUpload="win.uploadImage((UploadEvent) event)" />
        <div id="image" width="100px" height="100px" />
    </hbox>
</window>
```

and the class:

```
import org.zkoss.util.media.Media;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.UploadEvent;
import org.zkoss.zul.Div;
import org.zkoss.zul.Fileupload;
import org.zkoss.zul.Image;
import org.zkoss.zul.Messagebox;
import org.zkoss.zul.Window;

public class WindowController extends Window {

    private Div image;

    public void uploadImage(UploadEvent event) {

        Media media = event.getMedia();
        if (media instanceof org.zkoss.image.Image) {
            Image im = new Image();
            im.setContent((org.zkoss.image.Image) media);
            im.setParent(image);
        } else {
            Messagebox.show(media + " is not an image", "Error", Messagebox.OK, Messagebox.ERROR);
        }
    }

}
```

the image just did not appear in 'div' tag, but when I choose another type of file (not an image) it shows the messagebox which means that the condition was right. thank you

Comment: Have you solved this problem ? If solved don't forget to share...

Answer (score 1):

The Div image is null. retrieve it with `getFellow("image")`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add annotation above the onUpload method @Listen("onUpload=#uploadButton")

Answer (score 0):

change the yor div by:

```
<image id="idBtn"/>
```

and your method:

```
public void onUpload$idBtn(UploadEvent event) {
    Media media = event.getMedia();
    if (media instanceof org.zkoss.image.Image) {
        img_identificacion.setContent((org.zkoss.image.Image) media);
    }
}
```